# Can `docker compose watch` display container logs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was hoping to use [docker compose watch](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/) for local development with automatic restart when I edit the source files... But it seems like the container logs don't propagate through to the terminal like they do with `docker compose up`: I only see events for the watcher itself, like:

```
[+] Restarting 1/1
 ✔ Container app-web-1  Started
```

Of course this makes debugging trickier...

I couldn't see any relevant [CLI options for the watch command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_watch/). Even running `docker compose logs -f` in a separate terminal is not ideal because it seems to exit every time `watch` triggers a restart.

Does anybody know of a way to run `docker compose watch` but also see the live logs for containers in the same terminal, similar to `docker compose up`?

Comment: You can always run `while :; do docker compose logs -f; done` (in another terminal)